# What is the point of the controller action new and create having the same new method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working on several rails tutorial and I don't understand why the method `new` and method `create` both have

```
@example = Example.new
```

What is the point for the `new` method to have `@example = Example.new` when all this controller action does is to render the `new` page?

Comment: may be the _new page_ requires an `@example`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### New

@example = Example.new meaning to prepare your form so user can fill the data in form and @example instance will hold the value.

#### Create

@example = Example.new meaning create new object to save your data into database inside create usually @examle.save, this will save your data that  passed from new (through params)

Comment: Can't the create action prepare and create the object instead of the new action having to prepare the form? It seems to me that the code is not DRY.

Comment: when you using @example inside your view, meaning the object instance has to be created first to hold temporary the data

Answer (score 0):

Within Rails' implementation of REST new and create are treated differently.

An HTTP GET to /resources/new is intended to render a form suitable for creating a new resource, which it does by calling the new action within the controller, which creates a new unsaved record and renders the form.

An HTTP POST to /resources takes the record created as part of the new action and passes it to the create action within the controller, which then attempts to save it to the database.

From the Ruby on Rails documentation about [create](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html):

**create(attributes = nil) {|object| ...}**

> Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.

From the Ruby on Rails documentation about [new](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-c-new):

**new(attributes = nil) {|self if block_given?| ...}**

> New objects can be instantiated as either empty (pass no construction parameter) or pre-set with attributes but not yet saved (pass a hash with key names matching the associated table column names). In both instances, valid attribute keys are determined by the column names of the associated table — hence you can‘t have attributes that aren‘t part of the table columns.

So `create` instantiates the new object, validates it, and then saves it to the database. And `new` only creates the local object but does not attempt to validate or save it to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the point for the new method to have @example = Example.new when all this controller action does is to render the new page?

Because it renders the page using the attributes of the `@example` object.

You may be assuming that on a newly initialised object, all the attributes will have a value of nil. This is not necessarily the case, because code in the model (an `after_initialize` callback, or an `enum`, for example) may be providing default values.

The controller code itself might provide default values also in some cases, either inferred from the current user or passed in through parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You will be having `create` method like this:

```
def create
  @example = Example.new(example_params)

  if @example.save
    redirect_to @example
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Notice that inside the `create` action `render` is getting used instead of `redirect_to` when save returns `false`. The `render` method is used so that the `@example` object is passed back to the new template when it is rendered.

You need to tell the user that something went wrong. To do that, you'll modify app/views/examples/new.html.erb to check for error messages:

```
<% if @example.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

We check if there are any errors with `@example.errors.any?`, and in that case we show a list of all errors with `@example.errors.full_messages`.

The **reason** why `@example = Example.new` in the `ExamplesController` is that otherwise `@example` would be `nil` in our view, and calling `@example.errors.any?` would throw an error.